# Force SeleniumHQ in docker container to close all browser sessions

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, docker

I run `selenium hub` in docker container to test web-sites. 
The relevant part of my `Dockerfile` is:

```
#https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
version: '3'
services:
selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-dubnium
    environment:
    - GRID_MAX_SESSION=15
    - GRID_TIMEOUT=180000
    - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=180000      
    networks: 
    - selenium-hub
chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-dubnium
    shm_size: 512MB
    volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
    - selenium-hub
    environment:
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=6
    - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
    - HUB_PORT=4444
    - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
    networks: 
    - selenium-hub
```

I write python 3.x scripts to connect to selenium. The usual routine is as following. But sometimes `driver` variable is lost because of external errors. In this case selenium grid holds pending browser sessions on which I've already lost control. Is it possible to force `Selenium hub` to close all browser sessions at once? How do I do it in `python`?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=cap) 
##
# commands to browser
##
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can structure your code using try/finally:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=cap)
try:
    ##
    # commands to browser
    ##
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

or create your driver as a context manager:

```
with webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=cap) as driver:
    ##
    # commands to browser
    ##
```

... both of these will always call `quit()` on your driver instance.

Note: even though these will unconditionally call `quit()`, that doesn't necessarily mean the browser will actually close.

Comment: "that doesn't necessarily mean the browser will actually close"
Does this mean there will eventually be unused browser windows all over the instance?